# How to make calculator in asp.net using javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio

Howdy!
I want to make calculator in asp.net. without involving html and ajax, I want to use java script with asp. Any guide??

Comment: ASP.NET is a server side technology, javascript a client-side. Why even mention ASP.NET if you just want to use client side stuff?

Comment: If your not using HTML how do you expect to display the controls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get started [here](http://javascript.about.com/od/guidesscriptindex/a/calc.htm) for JavaScript.  You really don't need ASP for a simple calculator although it wouldn't hurt anything to create an ASP project for this I suppose.  Just keep in mind, that in this case, shoehorning ASP into this project is definitely not necessary and probably a bit of overkill.

If you are interested in jQuery at all, there is a much better tutorial for a jQuery calculator [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/new-plus-tutorial-build-an-awesome-popup-jquery-calculator/).

Comment: but what if I want to use asp.net with this? mean I want to use components of asp i.e. buttons, text field.

Comment: then you absolutely can, and for your case, it might make sense since you want to learn ASP.  Just know that in this case, however, it is not necessary to use ASP.

Answer (score 1):

You obviously need HTML if you want to do this in a browser, otherwise you won't have any input controls. A *really* simple calculator can be easily made in a few lines of JavaScript (you don't even need jQuery). Something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function calculate()
    {
        var v = document.getElementById("data");
        alert(eval(v.value));
    }
</script>


<input type="text" id="data" />
<input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="calculate()" />
```

Just type your equation in the text box (eg. 2 + 4 / 10) and click the button!

Answer (score 0):

```js
var cnt = 0;

function addcount(x) {
    var y = document.getElementById("text1").value;
    var l = y.length;
    var last = y.charAt(l - 1);
    if (last != x) {
        cnt = 0;
    }
    cnt = parseInt(cnt) + parseInt(1);
    if (cnt <= 1) {
        document.getElementById("text1").value += x;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("text1").innerHTML = '';
    }
}

function event1(m) {
    document.getElementById("text1").value += m;
    var z = document.getElementById("text1").value;
    document.getElementById("text3").value = eval(z);
    document.getElementById("text1").value = eval(z);
}

function event2() {

    var x = document.getElementById("text1").value;

    document.getElementById("text1").value = eval(x);
}

function event3() {
    document.getElementById("text1").value = "";
    document.getElementById("text3").value = "";
}

function event4() {
    var x = document.getElementById("text1").value;
    var sillyString = x.slice(0, -1);
    document.getElementById("text1").value = sillyString;
}
```

```css
.curve{
    border-radius: 13px;
}
.col{
    background-color: #00acc1;
}
.col1{
    background-color: #e8f5e9;
}
.col2{
    background-color: #1C2331;
}

#text1{

}
#text3{

}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Calculator</title>
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="curve" style="text-align: center;">
    <table  class="curve col2">
        <tr>
            <th colspan=6 class="curve col"><h1>Calculator</h1></th>
        </tr>
        <tr >
            <td colspan=6><input type="text" id="text1" class="curve col1" style="text-align:right;width:100%;"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr >
            <td colspan=6><input type="text" id="text3"  class="curve col1" style="text-align:right;width:100%;"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

            <td><button type="button" value="/" onClick="addcount(this.value)" class="curve btn-primary" style="padding:8px 14px;">/</button></td>
            <td><button type="button" value="." onClick="addcount(this.value)" class="curve btn-primary" style="padding:8px 14px;">.</button></td>
            <td><button type="button" value="*" onClick="addcount(this.value)" class="curve btn-primary"style="padding:8px 14px;">*</button></td>
            <td><button type="button" value="-" onClick="addcount(this.value)" class="curve btn-primary"style="padding:8px 14px;">-</button></td>
            <td><button type="button" value="" onClick="event3(this.value)"  class="curve btn-primary"style="padding:6px 18px;">C</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><button type="button" value="7" onClick="event1(this.value)" class="curve btn-primary" style="padding:7px 12px;">7</button></td>
            <td><button type="button" value="8" onClick="event1(this.value)"  class="curve btn-primary"style="padding:7px 12px;">8</button></td>
            <td><button type="button" value="9" onClick="event1(9)" class="curve btn-primary" style="padding:7px 12px;">9</button></td>
            <td rowspan=2><button type="button" id="ad"value="+" class="curve btn-primary" style="height:70px;padding:8px 13px;" onClick="addcount(this.value)">+</button></td>
            <td><button type="button" value="" onClick="event4(this.value)" class="curve btn-primary" style="padding:6px 10px;">DEL</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><button type="button" value="4" onClick="event1(4)" class="curve btn-primary" style="padding:7px 12px;">4</button></td>
            <td><button type="button" value="5" onClick="event1(5)" class="curve btn-primary" style="padding:7px 12px;">5</button></td>
            <td><button type="button" value="6" onClick="event1(6)" class="curve btn-primary" style="padding:7px 12px;">6</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><button type="button" value="1" onclick="event1(1)" class="curve btn-primary" style="padding:7px 12px;">1</button></td>
            <td><button type="button" value="2" onClick="event1(2)" class="curve btn-primary" style="padding:7px 12px;">2</button></td>
            <td><button type="button" value="3" onClick="event1(3)" class="curve btn-primary" style="padding:7px 12px;">3</button></td>
            <td rowspan=2><button type="button" class="curve btn-primary" style="height:70px;padding:8px 13px;" onClick="event2()">=</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="curve">
            <td><button type="button" class="curve btn-primary" onclick="event1(0)" style="padding:7px 12px;">0</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: looks good potentially, but you should probably provide some explanation of this large quantity of code.